# Where is the GIMP Python-fu documentation?

Tags: python, gimp

Simple as it is, where is the documentation and the API documentation? Is it available online?

Comment: https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/

Under 13. Scripting

Comment: @Mace that chapter is about script-fu and doesn't mention Python, even in the short paragraph about plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used to be [there](https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html) but [recently disappeared](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Infrastructure/gimp-web/-/issues/173).

Edit: as of April 2023, the doc has been reinstated and and can be found [at the expected place](https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html).

If it disappears again, it can still be found [on the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20190911072803/https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/index.html).

Note for future viewers: this is the doc for Gimp-2.x/Python-2.7, not for Gimp-3.x/Python-3.x.

Answer (score 1):

I have found documentation [here](http://www.jamesh.id.au/software/pygimp/).

It's old and I don't know if there is any difference with the doc that disappeared on the gimp site.

And I found this site [Sapper's Blog](http://sappersblog.blogspot.com/2017/06/writing-gimp-python-plug-ins.html). It seems to contain useful info and links about the subject.